# TableAdapter.insert - Get ID (With SCOPE_IDENTITY)? (SQL Server)

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

I can't figure out how to get the ID of the record created with tableadapter.insert() command.

I read several answers to similar questions but most of them shift to how to do it with COMMANDS and ADO or with Stored Procedures.

The closest I found was the recommendation to add SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to the end of the INSERT statement.

https://www.screencast.com/t/BU3F73ds

```
INSERT INTO [zGrid Filters and Layouts]
                     (XML, UserID, Type, Global, LastModDt, SaveName)
VALUES        (@XML,@UserID,@Type,@Global,@LastModDt,@SaveName);  

SELECT        SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

But when I do that, I get a "can't parse" error when I click Finish.

https://www.screencast.com/t/7R5MN3cF

Then I also set the Execute to Scalar.

https://www.screencast.com/t/w91RECeLUL2

And if I bypass that error, I get a runtime error saying I need to declare the scalar value.

https://www.screencast.com/t/RbNuizo65vu

I've verified my INSERT (SQL) code. In fact, I've confirmed it does insert without the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY line.

```
Dim ID As Int32 =
    DataTableGridFiltersLayoutsTableAdapter1.InsertRecord(xmlString, 
    1, "F", 1, Now, "My New Block 3")
```

I included the results, above.

To clarify, I want to figure this out using the generated table adapter -- unless the answer is you can't do it with table adapters (which doesn't seem right).

I've found countless articles that say it's possible but none of them actually show you how to do it -- beyond the tableadapter.insert line.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We don't like pictures of code around here.

Comment: The query builder UI won't be able to parse a query with an `INSERT` statement tacked onto it but it will still be successfully executed by the database.

Comment: I did not know pictures were discouraged. It seemed to me that screenshots would avoid a ton of back and forth about what I've actually done.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I'm getting an runtime error on the insert line, so the insert isn't getting executed.

Comment: Wow. So, maybe this question is harder than I thought. Maybe that's why none of the articles I found on it actually answer the question. All these experts here and no one knows how to do this?

Comment: @LarsTech, I didn't actually do pictures of code. I included the actual code in my comment. The screenshots were for context and of error messages.

Comment: The first picture is a query.  That is just text that could be formatted as code in your question.  This website just requires a four space indent for a code block.  The second image is an error message.  Again, text.  Use a > sign to make a quote block.

Comment: When I filled out the form, there was a textbox for code. That's where I placed the code. I assumed since it was a dedicated box, it would handle the formatting for me. Is there a way I can edit my question so you'll actually answer it?

Comment: I was simply trying to get your question in a better state.  Most programmers probably avoid the database designer tools and just work with the database directly in code.  I'm not familiar with that InsertRecord function you have.  It doesn't actually google well.